# Android studio only show blank files

Tags: android-studio

I closed the emulator tab and all of a sudden no files can be viewed, except the first row of one .arb language file.

It doesn't matter what kind of file it is, it's not showing up and I can't write anything in the text window.
I quit android studio and restarted the computer but it still the same.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Close the project, then open it via `file-> open...` and select your root folder.
After that it works again!